# multiple domain names in Nginx

Tags: nginx

We only have one server block. I was using server_name previously and have been adding domain names to it.

```
server_name example.com example.net hiscompany.org mycompany.net;
```

Those are just few but it's growing. On my machine, I recreated the configuration but I deleted `server_name` and I restarted Nginx. For my test, I added all the 10 different domain names or FQDNs into my /etc/hosts file. I tested our frontend application by using each FQDN I defined in my /etc/hosts file. I was able to load the website worked pretty well. I am not concerned about the content since the content that will be served are the same for all of the different FQDNs we will be using.

Do you see any issue with this kind of configuration which is deleting the `server_name`? If I keep adding fqdn to `server_name`, the config is going to look messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue you have with this approach is that nginx will serve the content for ANY domain name not explicitly defined in its configuration.
Also, in this case, I would use the "default" server_name, which is defined as:

```
listen <port> default_server;
server_name _;
```

Otherwise, it can be misleading and I am also not sure how nginx processes the rules when you have a server section defined without a server_name directive and also a server with a "default" server_name. 
The server_name can also be defined as a wildcard or using regular expressions but by the way it looks in your case, it won't help.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do some test using that code.